# how to add to cell into tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, xcode4.3

is it possible to add 2 `cell.textlabel` into the table view. As i want trying to display 3 different lines.
Here the code i did :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]; //Change this value to adjust size
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@","Walk to and board at ",[boardDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@","Alight Destination = ",[alDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
return cell;
}
```

but when i put two `cell.textLabel.text` it got an error `bad access`. what should i do?
Pls help

Comment: You'll have to better describe the error message you're receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only call cell.textLabel.text once, but put a \n in your string where you want a line break.

You also have an error in your stringWithFormat -- either put an @ in front of "Walk to and board at" or just remove that first %@, and have :

stringWithFormat:@"Walk to and board at  %@",[boardDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

So, to make it 2 lines you want this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Walk to and board at %@\nAlight Destination = %@",[boardDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[alDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: another qn is the a way to limit the number of words per line? because a longer string the table will show `...` behind

Comment: I don't know a way to do that.  You could make your cell bigger, and make the cell label 3 or 4 lines.